# Display items from list in viewbag in foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have list in `ViewBag` as `ViewBag.allteacherlist`. I want to show its element in `foreach` loop. I've done as follows:

```
<table>

        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.allteacherlist
            as List <TEAMS_PP.Data.TeacherEval>)
            {         
           <tr><td>    @item.AllTechersList() </td> </tr>

            }

</table>
```

This is giving me the error `object not set to referance of an object`. The list does come in `ViewBag.allteacherlist`

What am I doing wrong?

Code for viewbag:

```
List<TEAMS_PP.Entity.account> list = new TeacherEval().AllTechersList();
            ViewBag.allteacherlist = list;
```

Comment: Could you please add the relevant code for storing the list inside the `ViewBag`? I have a hunch that the problem comes from the casting (`as` will give you `null` when you don't cast correctly).

Comment: sir, i have added it. plase have a look at it

Answer (score 2):

[`as` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) converts a value to a given type, when possible, or `null` otherwise. The statement:

```
var result = originalValue as SpecificType;
```

is similar to:

```
var result = originalValue is SpecificType ? (SpecificType)originalValue : null;
```

If `ViewBag.allteacherlist` is not of type `List<TEAMS_PP.Data.TeacherEval>` or a type which inherits from `List<TEAMS_PP.Data.TeacherEval>`, you'll get a `null`, which would lead to "Object not set to reference of an object" exception.

Remember that collections (`Collection<T>`), for example, don't inherit from lists. On the other hand, most sets you deal with implement `IEnumerable<T>`. Unless you use specific features of a `List<T>`, use `IEnumerable<T>`. Be as much permissive as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The `ViewBag` is dynamic and stores objects as, well.. `object`s. You need to cast the list to its original type before using it.

```
<table>
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.allteacherlist
        as List <TEAMS_PP.Data.TeacherEval>)
        {         
            <tr><td>    @item.AllTechersList() </td> </tr>
        }
</table>
```

As noted by @MainMa in his answer, you need to specify the correct type in your cast, otherwise you will get `null` when using the `as` keyword. In your controller you were creating an object of type `List<TEAMS_PP.Entity.account>` but in your view you were trying to get an object of type `TEAMS_PP.Data.TeacherEval`. The `as` cast result was `null`.